# Can i have two Default ASPX pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Actually i've started to programm in ASPX using VB.NET as language i've made a client part website where the user can see different kind of products in the Default.aspx page and open a support ticket in another page.

Now i would make an admin part of the website and make a different Default page for it. So the question is it possible to show another Default.aspx page if an admin is logged?

Actually i'd accept all suggestion on how could i do it as better as possible.

Comment: I do not know how your level is in .NET, but I would recommend that you go for ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET MVC.

They are more flexible to develop.

MVC is flexible more than ASPX.
ASP.NET Core closer to how it develops today with other tools.

Comment: @DionnyPrensa actually i have to use ASPX as the company where i work use only it for web programming, so actually i just can make a normal aspx page like admin.aspx and if the user logged is an admin redirect him to that page instead of default?

Comment: **When you get the role of a logged user** you can redirect him to the desire page instead of default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using

```
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username.Value, True)
```

Instead of

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Value, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary.
You can have two pages and redirect or show the Admin's Page when the administrator is logged in.

Comment: But how can i authenticate the user and redirect him to administrator.aspx instead of default as for now to authenticate a user on login and redirect him i use    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Value, True) while like if i try to do "Response.Redirect("administrator.aspx")" if the user is an admin it doesnt work

Comment: How do you know when the user is an administrator?

Comment: i'm my database the user is registered as username password and role so i just make a select and check if in role table there is "ADMIN"

Comment: All right. Then when you have the role (only at that moment) you redirect the user to desire the page.

Comment: Just solved using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie instead of RedirectFromLoginPage